# How to install additional software to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have this docker-composer.yml

I need additional packages like graphicsmagick and others, how can i install it in docker component with DockerFile ?

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - php-fpm

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=mydbuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mydbpassword
    ports:
      - 3308:3306

  php-fpm:
    image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.3-fpm
    container_name: php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    links:
      - db
    working_dir: /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add

```
RUN npm install gm -g
```

in your Dockerfile ?
or if you have a package.json file, install all packages using the command:

```
RUN npm install
```

Comment: where i need to create Dockerfile and what to put inside him ?